# Change password in websphere application server

Tags: websphere, websphere-traditional

I am new to Websphere Application server , however I need to change the password of the users in federated file system through some utility . I can develop that utility in Java , however I need to know where will I get information about WAS command which I can used to change the password of the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `updateIdMgrLDAPBindInfo` utility.

1. Enter a wasadmin shell with `$WAS_HOME/bin/wsadmin`
2. Get command syntax and desc specific to your platform: `$AdminTask help updateIdMgrLDAPBindInfo`

A more detailed walkthorugh can be found on this IBM KC page:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twim_repos_pwd.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-3-1

Comment: This link is not working. Also I want to invoke this command from remote machine

Comment: @Harshal The same steps apply if you are doing this on a remote machine -- just do it through an ssh connection.  As for the link not working, the link doesn't support https, so is your browser blocking it because of that perhaps?

Comment: Is it possible to change default/OOB wasadmin password created during WAS install without disabling global security since we have ton of users/devs configured via LDAP repository as well?